# Looking for the best way to backup and restore a directory of sparse files

Tags: linux, backup, gzip, sparsefile

We have a  directory of sparse files (`du` returns 240M for one of these files; `ls` returns 960M).

When we copy one of these files over to S3, we end up uploading the entire 960M, and on downloading from S3, `du` now returns the full 960M.

We've tried `gzip`ping it, which reduces the upload/download sizes; but the extracted size is still 960M (using `du`).

Is there any way we can convert these files back into sparse files?

Comment: `best way to backup and restore a directory of sparse files` --> rsync

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this using **`fallocate --dig-holes`** given a recent version of util-linux.

Alternatively, `cp --sparse=always` will create a sparse file as the copy destination (then you can move it over the original).

Sparse files can be archived using the **`tar -S`** or `tar --sparse` option in GNU tar; e.g. `tar -czSf foo.tar.gz foo` if you also want compression, or `tar -cSf foo.tar foo` if you don't.